# ASP.NET - Dynamic compilation of aspx-files stopped working?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, compilation

I recently ran into some strange problems. Changes to files that are not code-behind (and not gets compiled to a DLL) should not require you to recompile the whole website, and this has never been I problem for me. These should actually get compiled dynamically when you first access the resource, e.g. the first time when browsing an updated aspx-page in the browser.

But yesterday, during development of a website, I noticed that even the smallest changes in html, javascript or anything in the .aspx-files doesn't get reflected when I save and reload the page in my browser. Rebuilding doesn't help either, actually I'll have to do a "Rebuild All" (in Visual Studio 2008) in order to see the changes. This applies to all aspx-files in my project.

I tried with minor changes on files in another web application project on the same server, and there it works as it should. Something must has happened to this particular application, but I cannot figure out what.
Do you have any ideas on how to solve this?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was the solution, but I noticed that I was running out of disk space. After some cleanup it started working again...